# How to create map[String,Class] and create its object dynamically in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

**Scenario :**
       I have a senario where I need to call Processor class one by one , which are required by the input provider by user , if not provided it should call all Processor class and process() method inside it.

**Code :**

```
class OneProcessor{}
class TwoProcessor{}
```

For this I am thinking of creating a Map[String, instanceOfClass] i.e:

```
val instanceMap:Map[String,Class] =Map(
    "string1" -> new OneProcessor(),
    "string2" -> new TwoProcessor(),
)
```

**Question :**
            if given string1 by user I need to create instance of OneProcessor() and execute it processor() method.

If user is not provided any input I need to call all keys of Map , and create instances of all classes and call processor() of all...

How to do this in `scala` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

Assuming all "processors" are doing similar things, I suggest extending them all from a trait instead of a using general class level constructs. Let's assume the following structure:

```
trait Processor {
  def process=println("default process")
}
case class ProcessorOne() extends Processor
case class ProcessorTwo() extends Processor {
  override def process=println("process 2")
}
case class ProcessorThree() extends Processor {
  override def process=println("process 3")
}
```

We create a map and put all `process` functions inside it:

```
val myFuncs =
  Map("string1" -> (() => ProcessorOne().process),
    "string2" -> (() => ProcessorTwo().process),
  "string3" -> (() => ProcessorThree().process))
```

Note that this is a `Map[String, Unit]`. Since your goal is to invoke functions, you don't really need to put instances in the map.

Now you can easily invoke any or all of these functions:

```
val userInput =""

if(myFuncs isDefinedAt userInput)
  myFuncs(userInput)()
else
  myFuncs.values.foreach(v => v())
```

The above will output:

```
default process
process 2
process 3
```

So if the key is not present in the map, all functions will be invoked (in no particular order), but if the key is in the map, only the function associated with that key will be invoked.

If you also need the functions to run in a particular order, you can use `LinkedHasMap` or `ListMap` to create a map which preserves the insertion order.

Comment: thank you so much sir , awesome ...let me try it and update you.

Comment: sir one more question , if my derived class objects has many methods defined , I need to call specific methods on the specific derived object , for provided key by user , then how to get specific class object from map and call methods on it ?

Comment: trait XTrait{
    
   def show
(x:String) : Unit
}

class One extends XTrait{
    def show(x:String )  = println("in class One x :" + x)
}



class Two extends XTrait{
    def show(x:String )  = println("in class Two x :" + x)
}

Comment: object ObjectMapper {
  
   
def main(args: Array[String]) {
 
     
val objMap: Map[String,XTrait] = Map(
  
        "one" -> new One(),
 
         "two" -> new Two()
         
 )
 
  
objMap.keys.foreach( key => {
          
         
         val obj:Option[XTrait]  = objMap.get(key);   /// it is not casting directly into XTrait . 
 
         obj.    /// this is not giving show method to call ..... What to do ??? What am i doing wrong here 
          
          
         
       
     }
     )
      
 
}

Comment: val obj:Option[XTrait]  = objMap.get(key);   /// it is not casting directly into XTrait .

Comment: obj.    /// this is not giving show method to call ..... What to do ??? What am i doing wrong here

Comment: sir i tried but there is compiler error   val userInput ="string1"
   
if(myFuncs isDefinedAt userInput) // Error : not found: value myFuncs
  myFuncs(userInput)() // Error : not found: value myFuncs
else
  myFuncs.values.foreach(v => v()) // Error : not found: value myFuncs

Comment: sir my mistake but when i called only myFuncs.values.foreach(v => v())                     // Error unit does not take parameters

Comment: @user3252097, I am not getting that error running in a Scala worksheet. Please edit your question with the exact code you are running.

Comment: sir i am using eclipseScalaIDE. unable to edit the main query ...just copy paste bellow snippet

Comment: trait Processor {
                          def process()=println("default process")
                        }
                        case class ProcessorOne() extends Processor
                        case class ProcessorTwo() extends Processor {
                          override def process=println("process 2")
                        }
                        case class ProcessorThree() extends Processor {
                          override def process=println("process 3")
                        }

Comment: I don't understand why you need casting. You asked how to invoke methods. Scala allows you to directly put functions as map values. You don't need to put instances in the map if you only want to invoke a function. If there are just a few methods, you may even be able to forget about classes and directly put functions in the map. It really depends on the use case.

Comment: object DemoProc {
def main( args : Array[String]):Unit ={  
     val myFuncs : Map[String, Unit]=
                          Map(
                            "string1" -> (() => (new ProcessorOne()).process),
                            "string2" -> (() => (new ProcessorTwo()).process),
                            "string3" -> (() => (new ProcessorThree()).process)
                          )
                          
                           myFuncs.values.foreach(v => v());// Error Unit does not take parameters
  }
}

Comment: Comments are not really a good place to answer questions. You can ask another question though. Also if you put code inside ` character, it will look like this : `code` which is easier to read.

Comment: The reason you are getting that error by the way is that `myFuncs` type is not what you are ascribing to  it: change it to `Map[String, () => Unit]` and it will work.

Comment: oh ....Thank you so much sir its working but how to call method which takes arguments i.e. process( x: Xtype) ???

Comment: trait Processor0 {
  def process(x:String): Unit 
}
case class Processor2() extends Processor0 {
  override def process(x:String): Unit = println("Processor2 x :" + x)
}
case class Processor3() extends Processor0 {
  override def process(x:String): Unit = println("Processor3 x :" + x)
}

Comment: object DemoProc2 {
  def main( args : Array[String]):Unit ={
  val s:String = "yes"
  val myFuncs: Map[String,(x: String) => Unit ]=    //Error : ')' expected but ':' found. 
      Map(
    "string2" -> (() => (new Processor2()).process(s),
    "string3" -> (() => (new Processor3()).process(s)
  )
   myFuncs.values.foreach(v => v());
  }
}

Comment: this is not working sir ,  val myFuncs: Map[String,(x: String) => Unit ]=    //Error : ')' expected but ':' found.

Comment: sir my mistake , but now something wierd from class it is not recognizing the running classes   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007811/how-to-fix-this-error-not-found-value-bmvalsprocessor

Answer (score 0):

You can call `newInstance` method to create instances out of class.

```
classOf[OneProcessor].newInstance
```

Comment: @sir how i know object from map value is OneProcessor or TwoProcessor to call classOf ?