# How to fix this error "not found: value BMValsProcessor"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to fix this error in this code

```
trait Processor00 {
  def process(oraOptionDfConfig: DataFrameReader, sparkSession: SparkSession ): Unit 
}

class BMValsProcessor extends Processor  {
   def process(oraOptionDfConfig: DataFrameReader, sparkSession: SparkSession ) : Unit ={
     println("in BMValsProcessor")///actual business logic
   }
}

class BMValsProcessor2 extends Processor  {
   def process(oraOptionDfConfig: DataFrameReader, sparkSession: SparkSession ) : Unit ={
     println("in BMValsProcessor2") //actual business logic
   }
}

object ValProcessor {
   def main( args : Array[String]):Unit ={

     val df : DataFrameReader = null; // initialization of DataFrameReader
     val spark: SparkSession = null; // initialization of SparkSession

      val procs :Map[String, (DataFrameReader, SparkSession) => Unit] = getAllDefinedProcessors();

       procs.values.foreach(
                proc => proc(df,spark) 
        )
   }

    def getAllDefinedProcessors(): Map[String, (DataFrameReader, SparkSession) => Unit] = {
     val myFuncs2 : Map[String, () => Unit]=
      Map(
        "bm_vals" -> (() =>  BMValsProcessor().process), //Error
        "bm_vals2" -> (() => BMValsProcessor2().process) //Error
      )
      myFuncs2;
   }

}
```

The error is:

> not found: value BMValsProcessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression `BMValsProcessor()` is call method `apply` of object `BMValsProcessor`

Look into https://gist.github.com/AndriiStefaniv/902938c71440c3f25769528e5c730d4f

I tried to fix it.

Comment: Sir  I am confused in one aspect earlier this worked https://gist.github.com/shatestest/1e2a1eac4de10199a1fbc693a7d48c09
Now I have confusion when to use 
1 ) "new BMValsProcessor().process" 
2) "(() => (new ProcessorOne()).process)
3) Why not "new ProcessorOne().process()"

Comment: Look https://gist.github.com/AndriiStefaniv/902938c71440c3f25769528e5c730d4f#gistcomment-2743487. I answered there