# Dynamic object creation with arguments

Tags: scala, scala-collections

**Scenario** :
This is modified version of the requirements mentioned in this below blog.

[How to create map[String,Class] and create its object dynamically in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971763/how-to-create-mapstring-class-and-create-its-object-dynamically-in-scala/63021925#63021925)

I have a senario where I need to call class one by one which is implements trait based on the input provider by user , if not provided it should call all Processor class and process() method inside it.

```
trait Processor {
  def process(str:String)=println("default process")
}
case class ProcessorOne() extends Processor
case class ProcessorTwo() extends Processor {
  override def process(str:String)=println("process:"+str)
}
case class ProcessorThree() extends Processor {
  override def process(str:String)=println("process:"+str)
}
```

Now my problem is how can I create a Map[String,Class] to dynamically pick the particular class based on user input key and pass the particular arguments which user is passing.

```
val myFuncs =
  Map("string1" -> (() => ProcessorOne().process),
    "string2" -> (() => ProcessorTwo().process),
  "string3" -> (() => ProcessorThree().process))
```

Say if user is saying string2 as key and its corresponding class argument as 15.
I should get output as process:15.

If user is passing string3 as key and class argument as 20. Then corresponding object of processor 3 should be called and output of process:20. Should be printed.

I am new to scala. Please advise for me. Any other approach for dynamically picking scala classes with user supplied arguments are welcome.

Comment: I do not understand, what is the question? How to use the map? How to magically create the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need a 'dynamically picking' class.
You want to get a function, that creates a new object of the picked class.
Your variant

```
val myFuncs =
  Map("string1" -> (() => ProcessorOne().process),
      "string2" -> (() => ProcessorTwo().process),
      "string3" -> (() => ProcessorThree().process))
```

Is quite good.

So imagine that we have user input as parameters of the function

```
object SomeServiceThatProcessUserInput {
  private val implementationCreators: Map[String, () => Processor] = 
    Map(
      "string1" -> () => ProcessorOne(),
      "string2" -> () => ProcessorTwo(),
      "string3" -> () => ProcessorThree()
    )

  def processUserInput(implementationChooseString: String, anotherInput: String) = {
    val implementationCreator: () => Processor = implementationCreators .get(implementationChooseString).getOrElse(throw new Exceprtion())
    val implementation: Processor = implementationCreator()
    implementation.process(anotherInput)
  }
}
```

You don't need to deal with `Class` at all.

If you want to use your Map with additional `.process` in it:

```
object SomeServiceThatProcessUserInput {
  private val implementationFunctionCreators: Map[String, () => String => Unit] = 
    Map(
      "string1" -> () => ProcessorOne().process,
      "string2" -> () => ProcessorTwo().process,
      "string3" -> () => ProcessorThree().process
    )
  def processUserInput(implementationChooseString: String, anotherInput: String) = {
    val implementationFunctionCreator: () => String => Unit = implementationFunctionCreators.get(implementationChooseString).getOrElse(throw new Exceprtion())
    val implementationFunction: String => Unit= implementationFunctionCreator()
    implementationFunction(anotherInput)
  }
}
```